# Angular 1 - Usando os bindings no controller - Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

Estou usando AngularJs, na criação de um component eu preciso acessar os bindings no controller do meu component.

No html estou chamando o component assim:

```
<component type='tipo' urlid='meuid'></component>
```

Eu estou usando a segunda syntax para os bindigs:

```
bindings: {
    type: '@',
    urlid: '@'
}
```

E no controller estou usando:

```
function meuController() {
    var vm = this;
    console.log(vm);
    console.log(vm.type);
    console.log(vm.urlid);
}
```

Estou tendo este retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é possivel ver na imagem os atributos então no controller(vm) mas quando eu acesso eles eu recebo o retorno `undefined`.

Como eu faço para acessar esses atributos?

Comment: Dentro do html do seu componente, tente usar $ctrl.nomeDoAtributo

Comment: Usando $ctrl.nomeDoAtributo no html eu estou conseguindo acesar os dados. O problema é que eu preciso utilizar eles no controller do meu component.

Comment: No meu código eu faço uma referencia ao escopo desse jeito: "var self = this;", e no controller, para acessar os atributos, utilizo self.nomeDoAtributo

Comment: Ata, fiz confusão aqui, desculpa, já tentou acessar usando vm["type"] ?

Comment: Usando `vm['type']` eu tenho o mesmo retorno `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Segue código abaixo:

```
vm.$onInit = function () {
    console.log(vm.type);
    console.log(vm.urlId);
}
```

Assim ele somente irá acessar o bind quando o controller for iniciado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui acessar os dados usando `$timeOut`, dessa forma:

```
$timeout(function () {
    console.log(vm.type);
    console.log(vm.urlId);
})
```

Possivelmente existe algum delay para o Angular reconhecer os parametros. Desta forma estou tendo o retorno.